# How to make input always below

Tags: java, logging, input

I have the following problem. When I input something and in the console will be printed a message, it will display like the following: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFVul.png)

I want to make the input always at the bottom.

Here my code:
CloudLogger:

```
package net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.logging;

import jline.UnsupportedTerminal;
import jline.console.ConsoleReader;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.CloudServer;
import net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.logging.async.AsyncPrintStream;
import net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.logging.util.FileFormatter;
import net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.logging.util.LoggingFormatter;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.*;

/**
 * A logger class with file logging.
 */
@Getter
public class CloudLogger {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final ConsoleReader consoleReader;
    @Setter
    private LoggingFormatter loggingFormatter;
    @Setter
    private FileFormatter fileFormatter;

    /**
     * Constructor of the {@link} CloudLogger class.
     */
    public CloudLogger() throws IOException {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("CloudServerLogger");
        (consoleReader = new ConsoleReader(System.in, System.out, new UnsupportedTerminal())).setExpandEvents(false);
        LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler();
        loggingFormatter = new LoggingFormatter();
        fileFormatter = new FileFormatter();

        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        File folder = new File("logs/");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File latest = new File("logs/latest.log");
        if (latest.exists()) {
            latest.renameTo(new File("logs/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log"));
        }

        FileHandler fileHandler = null;
        try {
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("logs/latest.log");
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        loggingHandler.setFormatter(loggingFormatter);
        loggingHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(loggingHandler);

        fileHandler.setFormatter(fileFormatter);
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

        System.setOut(new AsyncPrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Level.INFO)));
        System.setErr(new AsyncPrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Level.SEVERE)));
    }

    /**
     * Logs an information.
     *
     * @param message Message that has to be logged. See {@link String}
     */
    public void info(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }

    /**
     * Logs an debug-message.
     *
     * @param message Debug-Message that has to be logged. See {@link String}
     */
    public void debug(String message) {
        if (CloudServer.getInstance().isDebug()) logger.config(message);
    }

    /**
     * Logs an warning.
     *
     * @param message Warn-Message that has to be logged. See {@link String}
     */
    public void warning(String message) {
        logger.warning(message);
    }

    /**
     * Logs an error.
     *
     * @param message Error-Message that has to be logged. See {@link String}
     */
    public void error(String message) {
        logger.severe(message);
    }

    /**
     * {@link LoggingHandler} class
     */

    private class LoggingHandler extends Handler {

        public LoggingHandler() {
            try {
                this.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void publish(final LogRecord record) {
            if (this.isLoggable(record)) {
                try {

                    consoleReader.print(loggingFormatter.format(record));
                    consoleReader.println();
                    consoleReader.flush();

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link LoggingOutputStream} class
     */
    private class LoggingOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {

        private final Level level;

        public LoggingOutputStream(final Level level) {
            this.level = level;
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            final String contents = this.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            super.reset();
            if (!contents.isEmpty() && !contents.equals(System.lineSeparator())) {
                CloudLogger.this.getLogger().logp(this.level, "", "", contents);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Console:

```
package net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.console;

import jline.console.ConsoleReader;
import jline.console.completer.CandidateListCompletionHandler;
import lombok.Data;
import net.kolania.cloud.cloudserver.CloudServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Console extends Thread {

    private ConsoleReader consoleReader;
    private List<Command> commands;

    public Console(ConsoleReader consoleReader) {
        this.consoleReader = consoleReader;
        consoleReader.setPrompt("");
        consoleReader.setCompletionHandler(new CandidateListCompletionHandler());
        commands = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line;
        String[] split = null;

        try {
            while (!isInterrupted() && (line = consoleReader.readLine()) != null) {
                console(line, split);
                line = null;
                split = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void console(String line, String[] split) {
        if (line.contains(" ")) {
            split = line.split(" ");

            for (Command command : commands) {
                if (command.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(split[0]) || command.isAlias(split[0])) {
                    if (split.length != 1) {
                        if (command.handleSubCommand(split[1], Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 2, split.length))) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    command.handle(Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length));
                    return;
                }

            }

            CloudServer.getLogger().info("This command does not exist, type 'help' for a list of all available commands.");
        } else {

            for (Command command : commands) {
                if (command.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                    command.handle(null);
                    return;
                }
            }

            CloudServer.getLogger().info("This command does not exist, type 'help' for a list of all available commands.");
        }
    }

    public void addCommand(Command command) {
        commands.add(command);
        consoleReader.addCompleter(command.getStringsCompleter());
    }

    public void removeCommand(Command command) {
        commands.remove(command);
        consoleReader.removeCompleter(command.getStringsCompleter());
    }

    public boolean isCommandExists(Command command) {
        return commands.contains(command);
    }

    public List<Command> getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }

}
```

If you need more code, please post it here.
I hope you can help me or give me another solution.

Sincerely,
Skyleiger

P.s. Sorry for my bad english, but I am german. I hope that you can understand everything.

Comment: What has been typed or printed in the console window is water under the bridge. If you want to have a more sophisticated (= raffinierteres) terminal-like window you'll have to look into javax/swing/JTextArea for displaying your standard output data and use a separate JTextField for input.

Comment: @laune Okay, thank you, but how can I do that in an console application? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/19834155/jtextarea-as-console